# Get records between date range

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to fetch a row which comes in a particular date range

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ((s_tdate <= '2016-05-26' OR `e_expiredate` >= '2016-05-26') OR (`s_tdate` <= '2017-09-11' AND `e_expiredate` >= '2017-09-11') OR (`s_tdate` >= '2016-05-26' AND e_expiredate <='2017-09-11'))

  $this->db->select(*);
  $this->db->where("((s_tdate <='$start_date' AND e_expiredate >= '$start_date')");
  $this->db->or_where("(s_tdate <='$end_date' AND e_expiredate >='$end_date')");
  $this->db->or_where("(s_tdate >='$start_date' AND e_expiredate <='$end_date'))");
  $query = $this->db->get('table');
```

Am getting no result.

Please help

Comment: put OR conditions in between .. e.g. (s_tdate <= '2016-05-26' AND `e_expiredate` >= '2016-05-26') OR (`s_tdate` <= '2017-09-11' AND `e_expiredate` >= '2017-09-11') OR (`s_tdate` >= '2016-05-26' AND e_expiredate <='2017-09-11')

Comment: thank you.Tt was a mistake in my question.I put OR in my query but no result.Is the query correct?

Comment: you have to double check in your db about , may be no records found between your date, otherwise query is perfect now

Comment: can u explain exactly between which date u want to fetch a data, and what is the data type of your fields(s_tdate,e_expiredate)

Comment: got it! Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put **OR** conditions in between ..

```
e.g. (s_tdate <= '2016-05-26' AND e_expiredate >= '2016-05-26') OR (s_tdate <= '2017-09-11' AND e_expiredate >= '2017-09-11') OR (s_tdate >= '2016-05-26' AND e_expiredate <='2017-09-11')
```

**Please use this..**

Basically it will give query like s_tdate and e_expiredate in given range and provide  row which comes in a particular date range

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->where("s_tdate BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date");
$this->db->where("e_expiredate BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date");
$query = $this->db->get('table');
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If any doubt i will comment , please do help.Thanks once again

Comment: Hi, am getting a bug when using this query, suppose if i give 2016 and 2020 as start and end date nad database has records with maximum 2019 enddate only am getting the 2019 as result.i should not get any result actually.

Comment: i need to fetch records withing the range only, when i used this query am getting rows out of range.like greater than end date

Comment: $this->db->where("((start_date <='$start_date' AND end_date >= '$start_date')");
$this->db->or_where("(start_date <='$end_date' AND end_date >='$end_date')");
$this->db->or_where("(start_date >='$start_date' AND end_date <='$end_date'))");
$this->db->order_by('start_date','DESC');
$this->db->limit(1);

Comment: start_date :2016-05-27 end date = 2020-05-27.

Comment: Could you please send me the codeigniter query instead of your reply.

Comment: Thank you so much, let me check